# Apply formula to all rows

Tags: excel

I know you can apply a function/formula by clicking and dragging the bottom right, but I have a certain problem.

My function looks like this

```
=IF(COUNT(H3:N3)>0;SUMPRODUCT(H2:N2;H3:N3)/SUM(H2:N2);"")
```

I want all the other rows loook exactly the same, except for the COUNT and the second argument of the SUMPRODUCT.

So the next lines should look like this:

```
=IF(COUNT(H4:N4)>0;SUMPRODUCT(H2:N2;H4:N4)/SUM(H2:N2);"")
=IF(COUNT(H5:N5)>0;SUMPRODUCT(H2:N2;H5:N5)/SUM(H2:N2);"")
=IF(COUNT(H6:N6)>0;SUMPRODUCT(H2:N2;H6:N6)/SUM(H2:N2);"")
...
```

So my divisor stays the same and the numbers I multiply with as well (H2:N2).

When I drag by the right corner I always get this:

```
=IF(COUNT(H4:N4);SUMPRODUCT(H3:U3;H4:U4)/SUM(H3:U3);"")
```

Is there any way I can do this without changing each formula for each row?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must freeze the Cell reference using `$`:

```
=IF(COUNT(H3:N3)>0;SUMPRODUCT($H$2:$N$2;H3:N3)/SUM($H$2:$N$2);"")
```

- `$H$2` will keep the reference to both row and column,
- `$H2` will keep reference to the column and rearrange row on (vertical) drag,
- `H$2` will keep reference to the row and rearrange the column on (horizontal) drag.

Microsoft Tip: You can use the F4 key to auto add the dollar signs on your Cell reference.

Comment: Wow! Didn't know that. The F4 tip didn't work on the Mac, but still. That's good enough! Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome cherrun. I edited my answer to specify it's a Microsoft tip. ;)